# Kafka fails to create Topic with large number of partitions (64k)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am running Kafka 0.10.1.0 on Windows.

I am trying to create a large topic with 64k partitions using kafka-topics.bat. But it fails to create with error -

```
[2017-10-26 15:35:01,232] WARN Session 0x25f59be4474000f for server <ZK server name>/<ZK Server IP>:<ZK server port>, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.z
ookeeper.ClientCnxn)

java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:117)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:366)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
```

Anyone else faced this issue ever? Also, any known issues with having a Kafka topic with this large number of partitions? Or would I be better off splitting them across multiple topics?

Thanks,
Vinay

Comment: You will definitely want to divide the topic into smaller topics. The management of such high partition is problem for disk IO. Usually for such big data needs we set up zookeeper quorum of 5 and multiple Kafka brokers. These many partitions needs to be distributed over brokers for proper management

Answer (score 2):

To view the total number of handles (not just file handles) your application opened at a given time: Just to make sure it's the handle limit.

Download Process Explorer from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx Make sure to set appropiate refresh speed. Open it and go to View -> Select Columns -> press on the tab "Process Performance"and click on "Handle Count".

For Windows 7 x64 bit, a process can have 16.711.680 handles opened simultaneously. If you want to check limits for yourself then read below. Check that by using a tool from Windows Internals Book (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx). Tool's name is TestLimit and you will find it in the lower part of the page under the Book Tools header.

There are no ways to increase this limit for Windows Operating Systems as far as I know, and I looked also.

As others stated, think of a method to minimize the large number of threads. Maybe your application closes the file, but not the handle. My advice, if you really need using very large handle count, start a new process every time handle count is about 16m.

Answer (score 0):

Creating 64k partitions, requires as much as File Handlers. I haven't run the Kafka in Windows. But in linux, you have to increase the file handlers via `/etc/security/limits.conf`

This [article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-choose-the-number-of-topicspartitions-in-a-kafka-cluster/) might be useful to choose the right number of topic-partitions.